# How to map through an object in JavaScript and extract nested data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to iterate through this data structure to generate a Graph. But I couldnt figure out how to map through my Objects.

```
{
 "dP008S002D007":[
   571.8619718309859,
   604.5888966971188
  ],
 "dP009S002D007":[
   1445.2859154929577,
  1503.5495432185523
 ]
}
```

dp00... will be my line. So I'll map over this object and generate a Line, the values inside the array will be my data. But I cant figure out how to map over this structure. This was a dictionary and I managed to reduce to this.
Here is my code.

```
  const chartPoints = useMemo(() => {
    const history = iotData?.history?.[location.id].sensors || [];
    const chartPoints = {};
    const findPoints = Object.keys(history).map((key) => {
      chartPoints[key] = history[key].map((data) => data.avg);
    });
    return chartPoints;
  }, [iotData?.history, location.id]);
```

It'll be ideal if I could return:

```
[
 "dP008S002D007":[
   571.8619718309859,
   604.5888966971188
  ],
 "dP009S002D007":[
   1445.2859154929577,
  1503.5495432185523
 ]
]
```

Or map over these objects. Can Anybody help me with this? Thanks for all.

Comment: Your output is invalid, so you can't return it in that format.

Comment: this is as close as you can get: `Object.entries(obj).flat()`

Comment: In Js you cannot have string as array key, each key is an integer not a string like you did. If your key need to be any kind of string you should stick to the Object like it's

Comment: Looks very close to the `Map`  with string key and array as value

Answer (score 0):

As some answered to your question, you can't make a variable like you wanted in your output. But, because you just want to iterate throught your input you can use the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

In a for...in you can iterate like this :

```
for(key in obj) {
//key is the name of the key like "dP009S002D007"
//obj[key] is the value like [1445.2859154929577,1503.5495432185523]
}
```

else you can also transform your whole object as array of array with this one :

```
let table = []
for(key in obj) {
    table.push([key, ...obj[key]])
}
```

it produces 1 array containing 2 arrays like this :

```
[ [ 'dP008S002D007', 571.8619718309859, 604.5888966971188 ],
[ 'dP009S002D007', 1445.2859154929577, 1503.5495432185523 ] ]
```

You will then be able to use .map on the table and do what you wanted.